# In MySQL is there any difference when INT data type is explicitly stated to be UNSIGNED and when it is not?

Tags: mysql, datatable, integer, signed

In MySQL I can declare a table as -

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( column1 INT );
```

I can also declare a table as -

```
CREATE TABLE table2 ( column2 INT SIGNED );
```

So is there any difference between the two tables or are they same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from MySQL official documentation about [Numeric type syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html):

*"Numeric data types that permit the UNSIGNED attribute also permit SIGNED. However, these data types are signed by default, so the SIGNED attribute has no effect."*

Therefore both columns in your example above have the same datatype of `INT SIGNED`. Unless you're defining one of it as `UNSIGNED`, then there's a difference.